# Javascript card search filter card overview page

Tags: javascript, html, django

So I am currently building an overview page with a lot of cards which include data such as route name, number of routes, strarting point and date. Now im trying to build a filter using javascript where the user can filter on the route name, number of routes, strarting point and date so that the user can search for the specific card.

Currently I have 6 cards with data and when I type in the search input field it just deletes the first 4 cards and shows the last 2.

- I used some unnecessary classnames like route__text, these were just for the purpose of trying to fix my search filter.

My code:

Help would be greatly appreciated

```js
const input = document.getElementById('search');
input.addEventListener('keyup', search);

function search() {
  const inputValue = input.value;
  console.log(inputValue.toLowerCase());
  const routeContainer = document.getElementById('route');
  const routeDetail = routeContainer.getElementsByClassName('route__filter');
  console.log(routeDetail);

  for(let i = 0; i < routeDetail.length; i++) {
    let searchTerm = routeDetail[i].querySelectorAll(".route__parent td.route__text");
    // console.log(typeof searchTerm);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < searchTerm.length; i++) {
      let correctSearch = searchTerm[i];
      console.log(correctSearch.innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase());
      if (correctSearch.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())) {
        routeDetail[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        routeDetail[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } 
}
search();
```

```html
<div class="route" id="route">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end mb-4">
                        <input type="search" id="search" name="gsearch" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                        <div class="route__details">
                            <table class="route__table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Route name</th>
                                    <th>Stops</th>
                                    <th>Starting point</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="route__parent">
                                    <td class="route__text">Route one</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">3</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">City one</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter"> 
                        <div class="route__details">
                            <table class="route__table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Route name</th>
                                    <th>Stops</th>
                                    <th>Starting point</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="route__parent">
                                    <td class="route__text">Route two</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">3</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">City two</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                        <div class="route__details">
                            <table class="route__table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Route name</th>
                                    <th>Stops</th>
                                    <th>Starting point</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="route__parent">
                                    <td class="route__text">Route three</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">3</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">City three</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                        <div class="route__details">
                            <table class="route__table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Route name</th>
                                    <th>Stops</th>
                                    <th>Starting point</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="route__parent">
                                    <td class="route__text">Route four</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">3</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">City four</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                        <div class="route__details">
                            <table class="route__table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Route name</th>
                                    <th>Stops</th>
                                    <th>Starting point</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="route__parent">
                                    <td class="route__text">Route five</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">5</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">City five</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">21-09-2021</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                        <div class="route__details">
                            <table class="route__table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Route name</th>
                                    <th>Stops</th>
                                    <th>Starting point</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="route__parent">
                                    <td class="route__text">Route six</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">3</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">City six</td>
                                    <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works... Your code was very confusing to edit and point mistakes, but in general you should pay attention to a couple of things:

1. Note the difference between HTML Collections, Arrays and NodeLists
2. Avoid nesting for loops as they're confusing and hard to understand. In case you really need to use it, do not use the same variable name (`i` in your case) as it makes it confusing for the interpreter and other programmers.
3. `keyup` event trigger unnecessary `search` calls when no typing was made (i.e. shift or caps press)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const input = document.getElementById('search');
    input.addEventListener('input', search);

})

const search = (e) => {
  const inputValue = e.target.value;
  // console.log(`inputValue: ${inputValue.toLowerCase()}`);

  const routeContainer = document.getElementById('route');
  const routeDetail = [...routeContainer.getElementsByClassName('route__filter')];
  // console.log(routeDetail);

  for(let i = 0; i < routeDetail.length; i++) {
    let searchTerm = [...routeDetail[i].querySelectorAll(".route__parent td.route__text")];
    searchTerm = [...searchTerm.map((item) => item.innerHTML)];
    
    if (searchTerm.map(text => text.includes(inputValue)).some(val => val == true)){
      routeDetail[i].style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      routeDetail[i].style.display = 'none'
    }
  } 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="route" id="route">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end mb-4">
                <input type="search" id="search" name="gsearch" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                <div class="route__details">
                    <table class="route__table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Route name</th>
                            <th>Stops</th>
                            <th>Starting point</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="route__parent">
                            <td class="route__text">Route one</td>
                            <td class="route__text">3</td>
                            <td class="route__text">City one</td>
                            <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter"> 
                <div class="route__details">
                    <table class="route__table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Route name</th>
                            <th>Stops</th>
                            <th>Starting point</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="route__parent">
                            <td class="route__text">Route two</td>
                            <td class="route__text">3</td>
                            <td class="route__text">City two</td>
                            <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                <div class="route__details">
                    <table class="route__table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Route name</th>
                            <th>Stops</th>
                            <th>Starting point</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="route__parent">
                            <td class="route__text">Route three</td>
                            <td class="route__text">3</td>
                            <td class="route__text">City three</td>
                            <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                <div class="route__details">
                    <table class="route__table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Route name</th>
                            <th>Stops</th>
                            <th>Starting point</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="route__parent">
                            <td class="route__text">Route four</td>
                            <td class="route__text">3</td>
                            <td class="route__text">City four</td>
                            <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                <div class="route__details">
                    <table class="route__table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Route name</th>
                            <th>Stops</th>
                            <th>Starting point</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="route__parent">
                            <td class="route__text">Route five</td>
                            <td class="route__text">5</td>
                            <td class="route__text">City five</td>
                            <td class="route__text">21-09-2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 route__filter">
                <div class="route__details">
                    <table class="route__table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Route name</th>
                            <th>Stops</th>
                            <th>Starting point</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="route__parent">
                            <td class="route__text">Route six</td>
                            <td class="route__text">3</td>
                            <td class="route__text">City six</td>
                            <td class="route__text">20-09-2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <img src="{% static 'admin/img/svg/route-map.svg' %}" alt="map route" class="svg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you man! I have very limited experience in Javascript. Also thank you for the feedback I will improve my javascript alot in the coming weeks!